# Websocket unusual text connection

Tags: python, websocket, encoding, character-encoding

I want to make a websocket connection but I can't connect because the characters are unusual.

image:
[image]

```py
utf-8="m��6{�]���;G�=�͞�f�h�g�����YN����"
hex="1a6df68c367b865db387e60b3b479b3da3cd9ed166cf68b36708a5f891d5ec594ea0d903000000ffff"
base64="Gm32jDZ7hl2zh+YLO0ebPaPNntFmz2izZwil+JHV7FlOoNkDAAAA//8="
```

After decoding base64 in python, the output is:

```py
import base64
a = 'Gm32jDZ7hl2zh+YLO0ebPaPNntFmz2izZwil+JHV7FlOoNkDAAAA//8='
print(base64.b64decode(a))

RUN:b'\x1am\xf6\x8c6{\x86]\xb3\x87\xe6\x0b;G\x9b=\xa3\xcd\x9e\xd1f\xcfh\xb3g\x08\xa5\xf8\x91\xd5\xecYN\xa0\xd9\x03\x00\x00\x00\xff\xff'
```

I can't connect because I don't know what the send text.
How do I connect to server?

Comment: What is the URL for the server ?

Comment: @Heinz wss://gateway.discord.gg/?encoding=etf&v=9&compress=zlib-stream server of discord.com

Comment: If you just use wss://gateway.discord.gg/ you get  {"t":null,"s":null,"op":10,"d":{"heartbeat_interval":41250,"_trace":["[\"gateway-prd-main-pzjs\",{\"micros\":0.0}]"]}}

Comment: @Heinz how do i decode my above data? I didn't write it because the actual connection data is a bit long. I need information on how to decode this .

Comment: Looks Like this is Erlan Team Format. Go Here https://github.com/Pyrlang/Term